# Category Theory and Graph of a Function

Tags: category-theory

Let's assume I have a function between sets $X$ and $Y$, $f:X\to Y$. How can I view this as a subset of $X\times Y$? I am aware from category theory that a product comes equipped with two projection maps, so actually when we write $X\times Y$, we really mean $(X\times Y, p_x, p_y)$.

My question is this, am I guaranteed that there always exists a section of $p_x$, let's call it $s$, such that I can write $f=p_y \circ s_x$? Is this section unique? Is there any theorem with which one can check if a section exists?

Comment: I think it can be defined as the pullback of $f$ and $\mathrm{id}_Y$.

Comment: You don't need category theory for your first question. Simply consider the set $G=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y:f(x)=y\}\subseteq X\times Y\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathcal A$ be a category with binary products. Given $f_1 : Z \to A, f_2 : Z \to B$ there is a unqiue morphism $(f_1,f_2) : Z\to A\times B$, such that $p_A\circ (f_1,f_2) = f_1$ and $p_B \circ (f_1,f_2)$ (by the universal property of products).

Now in your case, we have $f = p_Y\circ (\operatorname{id}_X, f)$ and $p_X \circ (\operatorname{id}_X, f) = \operatorname{id}_X$. This morphism is unique (by the universal property of products).

In the case $\mathcal A = \mathsf{Set}$ we explicitly have:

$$(\operatorname{id}_X, f)(x) = (x,f(x))$$

---

Indeed, in category theory $(\operatorname{id}_X,f)$ is commonly defined to be the *graph* of $f$. The morphism $(\operatorname{id}_X,f)$ is obviously mono. A mono into $X\times Y$ is called a *relation* from $X$ to $Y$, so in this sense the graph of a morphism is a (categorical) relation.

Comment: Excellent! In the same lines, a "cograph" would be a retraction from $X+Y$; $R: X+Y\to Y$? GIven by $R=f$ if the element comes from $X$ and $id_y$ if the element comes from $Y$? Do I get this straight?

Comment: @user208272 Yes, I think you got that right. I don't know of any applicatons of *co*relations (in general) though (not to be confused with 'correlation').

Comment: Discrete dynamical systems. You can view the evolution as a bunch of arrows telling you which point you came from and which point you're heading.

Comment: @user208272 Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Do you have a reference?

Comment: There is a general notion of "image" of a morphism in category theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(category_theory) -- so I think it would make more sense to call the image associated to the morphism $(id_X, f)$ the graph of $f$, rather than calling $(id_X, f)$ itself the graph. Because the categorical image is related to the notion of pushout (the categorical dual of pullback), this also relates this answer to the above comment about possibly defining the "graph" in terms of a pullback.

Comment: @hasManyStupidQuestions There is no need to invoke the notion of an image because the image of a mono is the same mono, similarly if you work with equivalence classes.
Also images are directly related to pullbacks, because taking images is left-adjoint to taking pullbacks of subobjects (cf. the image-preimage adjunction).